# Bulk download PDFs from Google Scholar

Tags: google-scholar, bulk-download

I would like to download ~100 scholarly articles from Google Scholar. I have institutional access, so Google Scholar presents the available PDF. Is there a way to automate the downloading of the PDF files?

I realize that institutional access does not give me "permission" to bulk download. However, by having institutional access I can access the PDF directly from a link on the Google Scholar page, and am not behind a paywall.

Comment: Having institutional access does not imply having a permission for bulk downloads.

Comment: I'm not saying it does. I'm simply saying it allows me to download the PDFs directly from a link on the Google Scholar page.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that within Google Scholars. You need an external software to do this. Internet Download Manager has a grabber that can grab specific file formats from a webpage. Download and install, IDM, click grabber and set it up to download all the pdf files of that page.